# How to restrict a module/service from executing in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have multiple environments which gets provisioned using terraform. my question how to restrict a particular module from executing on a particular environment.

Eg: I need to deploy a instance service and associated module only in production, but not to lower environments

I have the below structure with services and each service calls modules.

structure:

```
├── instances
│   ├── config.tfplan
│   ├── data.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── modules
│   ├── buckets
│   │   ├── buckets.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── compartments
│   │   ├── compartments.tf
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── iam
│   │   ├── groups.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── policies.tf
│   │   ├── users.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── instances
│   │   ├── instance.tf
│   │   ├── output.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
```

[image]

Comment: What is your root module config declaring these modules?

Comment: All these are service folders and each service folder calls the child module within.

Comment: Would you mind giving us the example of your root module config ? So we can better guide you in answering the question. Without looking at the code and specifics, it would be hard to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not possible in older versions of Terraform but with version 0.12.6. You can add `for_each` in the module. Please find here an example of how I am using `for_each`:

Define variable:

```
variable "cloudwatch_event" {
  description = "Map of cloudwatch event configuration"
  type        = map(any)
  default = {
    default = {}
  }
}
```

Define resource:

```
module "cloudwatch_event" {
  source = "git::git@github.com:tomarv2/terraform-aws-cloudwatch-event.git?ref=v0.0.4"

  for_each = var.cloudwatch_event

  description  = lookup(each.value, "description", null)
  custom_input = lookup(each.value, "custom_input", null)
  suffix       = lookup(each.value, "suffix", "rule")
  schedule     = lookup(each.value, "schedule", null)

  deploy_event_rule   = var.deploy_cloudwatch_event_trigger
  deploy_event_target = var.deploy_cloudwatch_event_trigger

  target_arn = join("", aws_lambda_function.lambda.*.arn)
  #-----------------------------------------------
  # Note: Do not change teamid and prjid once set.
  teamid = var.teamid
  prjid  = var.prjid
}
```

As you can see if there is no `cloudwatch_event` this resource will not get deployed.

Please check the module repo located here: https://github.com/tomarv2/terraform-aws-lambda

Terraform documentation for your reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html